# clojure cannot apply function via map to list

Tags: clojure

I seem to have a difficulty understanding how I should use clojure `map`. I have a list of objects called `in-grids` where I wan't to use method `getCoordinateSystem`. I guess it is important that objects in the list are of some Java class. When I directly define function in clojure then `map` works.

This works:

`(.getCoordinateSystem (first in-grids))`

but not this

`(map .getCoordinateSystem in-grids)`

And the error is: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: .getCoordinateSystem in this context`

I'm probably missing something really obvious here, but what exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an expression of the form

```
(map f sequence)
```

then `f` should refer to an instance of `IFn` which is then invoked for every element of `sequence`.

`.` is a special form, and `.getCoordinateSystem` does not refer to an `IFn` instance.

```
(.getCoordinateSystem (first in-grids))
```

is equivalent to

```
(. (first in-grids) (getCoordinateSystem))
```

You can construct a function value directly e.g.

```
(map #(.getCoordinateSystem %) in-grids)
```

Comment: Perfect, I've used the `#( %)` construct before, but forgot here!

Answer (score 2):

Another choice which is often a handy alternative to `map` is the `for` function:

```
(for [grid in-grids]
  (.getCoordinateSystem grid))
```

Using `for` in this manner has the same effect as `map` but is a bit more explicit in the "one-item-at-a-time" nature of the processing.  Also, since you are calling the Java function `getCoordinateSystem` directly you don't need to wrap it inside a Clojure function literal.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Lee's answer, there's the `memfn` macro, which expands to code similar to that answer.

```
(map (memfn getCoordinateSystem) in-grids)

(macroexpand '(memfn getCoordinateSystem))
;=> (fn* ([target56622] (. target56622 (getCoordinateSystem))))
```

Comment: `memfn` is an older technique from the time before function literals `#(my-fn...)` and is now considered somewhat out-of-date.